# stack memory management in embedded systems

Tags: c, memory-management, stack, embedded

In a course I am taking about embedded systems there are certain statements which lack a deep explanation which has left me confused at some points. I would be grateful if someone can offer me clarifications.

1. I have been told that, if there are initialized variables, their initialization values are stored in the code segment (may be in flash) and are loaded (may be to RAM) by startup routines before running the program. This make sense to me considering global variables as they are allocated to .data section. I presume that global variables have a fixed address for the entire program and the initialization value is loaded to a specific address location(please correct me if I am wrong). Now, how is this done for local variables considering that they don't have a fixed address location on stack? Considering that local variables come to existence only during function execution, how do they get initialized each time the function is invoked?
2. Also, The instructor says, "The stack is reserved at compile time and the data is allocated at runtime by pre-compiled instructions". Can someone please make me understand the latter half of this statement?

Comment: The point of a stack is to "stack" function calls so that it's a LIFO structure. Every time you call a function, part of loading this function call to the stack is loading the local variables of this call to the stack. The local variable addresses are not fixed in the sense that they only exist during the lifetime of the specific function call and should only be accessed within that function context (accessed using the stack pointer). The amount of stack space your program has is OS dependent and sometimes can be changed (i.e. Java's stack size setting).

Comment: You can do same step to copy initialization data when you enter a function as well. Same mechanism, different piece of data. Nothing magic about that. If you recursively enter same function again, the same data is copied again ono another area on the stack.

Comment: As for "the data is allocated"...I assume this means local variables are allocated at runtime. When you run a program that's been compiled, all instructions are "pre-compiled instructions" so it seems like an unnecessary clarification for your instructor to add.

Comment: This might be helpful: [What resides in the different memory types of a microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237740/what-resides-in-the-different-memory-types-of-a-microcontroller/237759#237759)

Comment: @wxz Thanks for your comment. I was referring  from the context of embedded systems, especially bare metal. Stack saves not just local variables but also input parameters passed, return data, register values etc and it all makes sense to me. However, I wasn't clear how are the local variables initialized considering that their initialization values are present in flash. Since fetching data from flash in runtime doesn't sound practical, I wanted to understand how exactly it is done.

Comment: @Gerhardh Do you mean the compiler generates code to automatically copy the initialization values from flash to .data and then use that address to initialize the local variables?

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the details. Although it did not answer my question, It gave me useful information.

Comment: It depends on your system. In some system the whole program memory is copied from flash into RAM before it is executed. In some systems code is directly executed from flash. For the stack variables to be initialized, the compiler can also copy the content directly from flash. No need to copy anywhere else first.

Comment: @Lundin: in your linked examples `#define n 0                // .text` is not correct. It depends on for what n is used for. `uint8_t x = n;` or `uint8 array[n];` or  maybe in .text if used somewhere in the code `if (x <= n) {} `.

Comment: @kesselhaus From the text in the answer: "In the case of integer constants, initializer lists, string literals etc, they may end up either in .text or .rodata depending on compiler. Likely, they end up as: ..." And of course this isn't all too standardized in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of static variables the the `.data` section is correct.  You may also want to consider zero-initialized static variables in the `.bss` section.  These are initialized at the same time as those in the `.data` section, but their initial value does not need to be stored because it is zero.

Automatic variables may be on the stack or may be optimized to only be in processor registers.  Either way, code is generated by the compiler to initialize them each time the function using them is called.  If they are on the stack then this will include an instruction to adjust the stack pointer to "allocate" space for them when they are needed and "free" them when they go out of context.

The space for the entire stack is usually allocated in the linker script.  In an embedded microcontroller system no instructions are necessary to "allocate" it.  Depending on the hardware there may be code required to enable access to external memory, but in most cases there is a bank of fast SRAM ready to use as soon as the system powers on, and the first stack will be in this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That answered most of my doubts. So if the compiler chooses registers, I believe it uses immediate addressing mode and loads the initialization value directly to registers. Am I right? Also, If in case the stack is chosen, does it load the value from a specific address? If yes, where does that address lie? Because the initialization value lies in flash as a part of .cinit or .ctors, doe it fetch from there during run time? or does it copy to .data by startup routines and use that address instead?

Comment: This all varies depending on the platform and compiler, but for most compilers the value will be constructed in a register.  This may be using a load instruction or a "set immediate" type instruction (called MOV immediate on ARM).  If a load is used then this is probably from values kept inline with the instructions in the .text section, called a literal pool.  Once the value is constructed in a register it usually gets onto the stack with a push instruction.

Comment: If this helps, can you please accept the answer with the green tick mark on the left?  Thanks.

Comment: @Learner: It can do this in several ways, even by just doing an `xor r0, r0, r0` to initialize register `int a = 0;`. Or a `ldi r0, 123` (load immediate) for an `int a = 123;`. Though, it's part of the code and at the position where it is usually first used in a function, it does not have to be immediately at function entry.

Comment: @kesselhaus is there an echo in here?

Comment: @TomV: well sorry, I thought I also just would mention the not so obvious xor instruction to be used to initialize a value. It does not have to be all mv/ld. And it does not need to be pushed on the stack, if the compiler does the initialization directly in front of the calculation.

Comment: OK that makes sense, but you should specify that this only applies to x86 because on that platform it is a shorter opcode. Doing it on ARM is a bad idea, both because it is harder to read and on systems with out-of-order execution it creates a false dependency which actually makes the whole program slower.